How to add spinner animation code in the code and stop after finishing to load the page
I am trying to add Spinner in below code. I have tried many ways but not succussed.
I have included various position the spinner code but sometimes it runs but does not stop. Or some time never run.
Could you anyone help me to add spinner and stop after finishing to load the page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Dashboard - SB Admin</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script>            
                (function ($) {
                    "use strict";

                    // Spinner
                    var spinner = function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            if ($('#spinner').length > 0) {
                                $('#spinner').removeClass('show');
                            }
                        }, 1);
                    };
                    spinner();
        
        </script>
        
    </head>
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
        
        <!-- Spinner Start -->
        <div id="spinner" class="show bg-white position-fixed translate-middle w-100 vh-100 top-50 start-50 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Spinner End -->
        
        
        <nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">            
            
            <!-- Navbar Brand-->
            <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
            <!-- Navbar Search-->
            <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            
                
            <!-- Navbar-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Activity Log</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div id="layoutSidenav">
            <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                        <div class="nav">
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                                Dashboard
                            </a>
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Interface</div>
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseLayouts" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-columns"></i></div>
                                Layouts
                                <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="collapseLayouts" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                                <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layout-static.html">Static Navigation</a>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layout-sidenav-light.html">Light Sidenav</a>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsePages" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i></div>
                                Pages
                                <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="collapsePages" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                                <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav accordion" id="sidenavAccordionPages">
                                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseAuth" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseAuth">
                                        Authentication
                                        <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseAuth" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                                        <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="password.html">Forgot Password</a>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#pagesCollapseError" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pagesCollapseError">
                                        Error
                                        <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="pagesCollapseError" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordionPages">
                                        <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="401.html">401 Page</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link" href="500.html">500 Page</a>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Addons</div>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i></div>
                                Charts
                            </a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                                <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></div>
                                Tables
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
                        <div class="small">Logged in as:</div>
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <main>
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <h1 class="mt-4">Dashboard</h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard</li>
                        </ol>
                    
                        <div class="row">
                            
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Primary Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-warning text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Warning Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-success text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Success Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                                <div class="card bg-danger text-white mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-body">Danger Card</div>
                                    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
                                        <div class="small text-white"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-area me-1"></i>
                                        Area Chart Example
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body"><canvas id="myAreaChart" width="100%" height="40"></canvas></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-bar me-1"></i>
                                        Bar Chart Example
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body"><canvas id="myBarChart" width="100%" height="40"></canvas></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i>
                                DataTable Example
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table id="datatablesSimple">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Position</th>
                                            <th>Office</th>
                                            <th>Age</th>
                                            <th>Start date</th>
                                            <th>Salary</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Position</th>
                                            <th>Office</th>
                                            <th>Age</th>
                                            <th>Start date</th>
                                            <th>Salary</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                            <td>System Architect</td>
                                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                            <td>61</td>
                                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                            <td>$320,800</td>
                                        </tr>
                                       
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                            <td>23</td>
                                            <td>2008/12/13</td>
                                            <td>$103,600</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                                            <td>London</td>
                                            <td>30</td>
                                            <td>2008/12/19</td>
                                            <td>$90,560</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                                            <td>Support Lead</td>
                                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                            <td>22</td>
                                            <td>2013/03/03</td>
                                            <td>$342,000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                                            <td>36</td>
                                            <td>2008/10/16</td>
                                            <td>$470,600</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                                            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                                            <td>London</td>
                                            <td>43</td>
                                            <td>2012/12/18</td>
                                            <td>$313,500</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                                            <td>London</td>
                                            <td>19</td>
                                            <td>2010/03/17</td>
                                            <td>$385,750</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Michael Silva</td>
                                            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                                            <td>London</td>
                                            <td>66</td>
                                            <td>2012/11/27</td>
                                            <td>$198,500</td>
                                        </tr>
                                       
                                      
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                                            <td>Development Lead</td>
                                            <td>New York</td>
                                            <td>30</td>
                                            <td>2011/09/03</td>
                                            <td>$345,000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                                            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                                            <td>New York</td>
                                            <td>40</td>
                                            <td>2009/06/25</td>
                                            <td>$675,000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                                            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                                            <td>New York</td>
                                            <td>21</td>
                                            <td>2011/12/12</td>
                                            <td>$106,450</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                                            <td>Sidney</td>
                                            <td>23</td>
                                            <td>2010/09/20</td>
                                            <td>$85,600</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Fiona Green</td>
                                            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                                            <td>48</td>
                                            <td>2010/03/11</td>
                                            <td>$850,000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                       
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                                            <td>Technical Author</td>
                                            <td>London</td>
                                            <td>27</td>
                                            <td>2011/05/07</td>
                                            <td>$145,000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                                            <td>Team Leader</td>
                                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                                            <td>22</td>
                                            <td>2008/10/26</td>
                                            <td>$235,500</td>
                                        </tr>
                                       
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                                            <td>Secretary</td>
                                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                                            <td>41</td>
                                            <td>2010/02/12</td>
                                            <td>$109,850</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                                            <td>Director</td>
                                            <td>New York</td>
                                            <td>65</td>
                                            <td>2008/09/26</td>
                                            <td>$645,750</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      
                                      
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Donna Snider</td>
                                            <td>Customer Support</td>
                                            <td>New York</td>
                                            <td>27</td>
                                            <td>2011/01/25</td>
                                            <td>$112,000</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
                <footer class="py-4 bg-light mt-auto">
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between small">
                            <div class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2023</div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                                &middot;
                                <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="assets/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/demo/chart-bar-demo.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/umd/simple-datatables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/datatables-simple-demo.js"></script>        
        
    </body>
</html>



I have tried by this script
<script>            
                (function ($) {
                    "use strict";

                    // Spinner
                    var spinner = function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            if ($('#spinner').length > 0) {
                                $('#spinner').removeClass('show');
                            }
                        }, 1);
                    };
                    spinner();
        
        </script>

and html code
<!-- Spinner Start -->
        <div id="spinner" class="show bg-white position-fixed translate-middle w-100 vh-100 top-50 start-50 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Spinner End -->


It's hard to judge your problem without seeing the CSS in question. My suspicion is that removing show isn't enough to hide the element unless you have another class applying some kind of hide class. See the simplified example:


// Spinner
var spinner = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
      if ($('#spinner').length > 0) {
          $('#spinner').removeClass('show').addClass('hide')
      }
  }, 2000);
}

spinner();
.container {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Content
  </p>
  <div id="spinner" class="spinner show">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>




you can do like this
.spinner {
 display:none;
 ...rest of your css
}

.spinner.show {
 display:block;
 //or 
 display: block !important;
}

You can remove show class like this
 $('.spinner').removeClass('show');

And if you want to remove show when request done use "then" property of axios or fetch
someReqFunc().then(()=>{
 $('.spinner').removeClass('show');
})

or use finally
someReqFunc().finally(()=>{
 $('.spinner').removeClass('show');
})

#You must define spinner as classname at this situation
